What are homotopy groups of the quotients $SO(n+1,1)/SO(n,1)$ and $SO(n,2)/SO(n,1)$?
What are homotopy groups of the quotients $SO(n+1,1)/SO(n,1)$ and $SO(n,2)/SO(n,1)$ (in particular for $n=3$)? References would also be appreciated.
